# How to use Power Automate to mimic the bulk send tool in Adobe Sign using a CSV file

Tags: excel, csv, power-automate, power-platform, adobe-sign

I want to try schedule when an email comes in with an attachment of a CSV file, I want to try use that information to send bulk emails to retrieve signatures using a template pdf document I have.

All the details are in the CSV file and I just want to try do this using Power Automate Cloud and the in built Adobe Sign feature.

I have tried creating a flow but cannot figure out how to use the CSV file to fill out certain details on the template according to whoever the email is being sent to.